# Volunteer compensation, is it legal?

Tags: non-profit, salary, charity

Is paying to a nonprofit's officer less than the minimal wage legal?

Let a CEO of a nonprofit wants to pay to himself from his nonprofit a salary, but profit of the nonprofit is not enough to pay the minimum wage (of either Israel or US).

But it would be a silly restriction that he could not assign to himself a salary that he wants. It looks like that the law "protects" him from himself. It is his private deal how much to pay to himself, isn't it?

But I heard something about volunteer's compensation (like money for food during volunteer work). Can we apply something like this?

To be precise: consider the CEO of a nonprofit registered in Colorado, US, who lives in Israel (a citizen).

So, what are the ranges of possible salaries or compensations that he can pay to himself from the nonprofit? Will if he pays to himself such a compensation his work still considered volunteer?

Comment: This sounds like asking for direct legal advice...

Comment: @user71659 I changed the wording to eliminate this problem.

Comment: How is the non-profit “his” organisation?

Comment: @DaleM I mean that the CEO has full control over decisions of the nonprofit.

Comment: Not answerable to a board or members?

Comment: @DaleM No, I am currently a sole member of the nonprofit. And the bylaws are that I take all decisions sovereignly.